# LESS conditional padding?

Tags: css, less

Maybe conditional padding isn't the way to go, but -

I have a div that contains an `<img>`, which should fill up the available vertical space (90px) if it can, otherwise it should be centered vertically.  Here's a fiddle to demo the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/165/

How can I use LESS / CSS (not JS) to accomplish this?

```
// code for image
.folder-box img {
    max-height: 90px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Probably not, because what you want to do would need to be decided dynamically by the browser. LESS is just a language that compiles into CSS. You may need JavaScript for this

Comment: "Available space" means 90px height 100% width right?

Comment: Seems like a very simple task but my logic is failing right now.. Anyway, here's a nice read: http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt one of those methods must work for your use case.

Comment: That is a great article about centering, but the main problem with responsive design is that you don't want any height to have it's height declared - because it will depend on the situation. I believe that this is a javaScipt only solution. You'll have to find the heights of the parents and have some conditional logic. LESS is just a syntax that is processed into CSS, so if it can't be done in CSS, then it can't be done in LESS or SASS.

Comment: You are going to need to find the width of the parent... then find the width of the image - and have a conditional for whether the image is portrait or landscape - then either take the height or width depending on the case... hmmm

Comment: I would read about LESS guarded mixin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is a simple CSS problem, which can be solved by using vertical centering:

**<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/168/)</kbd>**

The only styles I've added are those of the images:

```
.folder-box img {
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Should you need defined space for your title element, you could simply wrap the image into another container and set `padding-bottom` and `position: relative`.

Comment: Thank you!  What if you want to limit the "available height" to the top 90px, so that the image never spans into the text, but is still centered above it?

Comment: Then you also need said container that wraps the image: **[Fiddle (first block)](http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/170/)**

Comment: Perfect, I knew it had to be something simple.  Thanks again :)